# Make UIBezierPath selectable and change it colour

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `UIView` which conform with a custom Canvas class. This means that the user can draw in that `UIView`.

Every time when the user finish to draw will need to click an Add `UIButton` and a row will be appended to an `UITableView` below.

Each row contains 2 properties `name: String`  and `scribble: [UInt8]`. The scribble property will hold the X and Y positions for the drawings associated with that row.

When the user is selecting any row from that `UITableView` then the colour of pixels will be changed on Canvas for that associated scribbles.

Here I have a demo from Android version and I need to do something similar: 
http://g.recordit.co/ZY21ufz5kW.gif

And here is my progress with the project but I'm stuck with the logic of appending X and Y coordinates and also I don't know how to do the selection of scribbles to be able to change the colour on Canvas:

https://github.com/tygruletz/AddScribblesOnImage

Here is my `Canvas` class:

```
/// A class which allow the user to draw inside a UIView which will inherit this class.
class Canvas: UIView {

    /// Closure to run on changes to drawing state
    var isDrawingHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?

    /// The image drawn onto the canvas
    var image: UIImage?

    /// Caches the path for a line between touch down and touch up.
    public var path = UIBezierPath()

    /// An array of points that will be smoothed before conversion to a Bezier path
    private var points = Array(repeating: CGPoint.zero, count: 5)

    /// Keeps track of the number of points cached before transforming into a bezier
    private var pointCounter = Int(0)

    /// The colour to use for drawing
    public var strokeColor = UIColor.orange

    /// Width of drawn lines
    //private var strokeWidth = CGFloat(7)

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
        path.lineWidth = 1
        path.lineCapStyle = .round
    }

    // public function
    func clear() {
        image = nil
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Draw the cached image into the view and then draw the current path onto it
        // This means the entire path is not drawn every time, just the currently smoothed section.
        image?.draw(in: rect)

        strokeColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }

    private func cacheImage() {

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        image = renderer.image(actions: { (context) in
            // Since we are not drawing a background color I've commented this out
            // I've left the code in case you want to use it in the future
//            if image == nil {
//                // Nothing cached yet, fill the background
//                let backgroundRect = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
//                backgroundColor?.setFill()
//                backgroundRect.fill()
//            }

            image?.draw(at: .zero)
            strokeColor.setStroke()
            path.stroke()
        })
    }
}

// UIResponder methods
extension Canvas {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first ?? UITouch()
        let point = touch.location(in: self)

        pointCounter = 0

        points[pointCounter] = point
        isDrawingHandler?(true)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first ?? UITouch()
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
        pointCounter += 1
        points[pointCounter] = point
        guard pointCounter == 4 else {
            // We need 5 points to convert to a smooth Bezier Curve
            return
        }

        // Smooth the curve
        points[3] = CGPoint(x: (points[2].x + points[4].x) / 2.0, y: (points[2].y + points [4].y) / 2.0)

        // Add a new bezier sub-path to the current path
        path.move(to: points[0])
        path.addCurve(to: points[3], controlPoint1: points[1], controlPoint2: points[2])

        // Explicitly shift the points up for the new segment points for the new segment
        points = [points[3], points[4], .zero, .zero, .zero]
        pointCounter = 1
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        cacheImage()
        setNeedsDisplay()
        path.removeAllPoints()
        pointCounter = 0
        isDrawingHandler?(false)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Here is my `ViewController` class:

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController {

    // Interface Links
    @IBOutlet private var canvas: Canvas! {
        didSet {
            canvas.isDrawingHandler = { [weak self] isDrawing in
                self?.clearBtn.isEnabled = !isDrawing
            }
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var clearBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addScribble: UIButton!

    // Properties
    var itemsName: [String] = ["Rust", "Ruptured", "Chipped", "Hole", "Cracked"]
    var addedItems: [DamageItem] = []

    // Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.image = UIImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "drawDamageOnTruck"))
        itemsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    @IBAction func nextBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        guard
            let navigationController = navigationController,
            let secondVC = navigationController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC
            else { return }

        let signatureSaved = convertViewToImage(with: mainView)

        secondVC.signature = signatureSaved ?? UIImage()

        navigationController.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func clearBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        canvas.clear()
        addedItems = []
        itemsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func addScribble(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let randomItem = itemsName.randomElement() ?? ""
        let drawedScribbles = [UInt8]()

        addedItems.append(DamageItem(name: randomItem, scribble: drawedScribbles))

        itemsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    // Convert an UIView to UIImage
    func convertViewToImage(with view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            view.layer.render(in: context)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension FirstVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return addedItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = addedItems[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("Click on \(addedItems[indexPath.row].name)")

        // Bold the selected scribble on the image.

    }

    /// This method is used in iOS >= 11.0 instead of `editActionsForRowAt` to Delete a row.
    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        let actionHide = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, view, handler in

            self.addedItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.itemsTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            handler(true)
        }
        actionHide.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [actionHide])
    }
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated !
Thanks for reading this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that you are taking stroked paths and flatting them down to an image. That’s a fine optimization (though generally one we only worry about if we have hundreds or thousands of points of strokes to render), but that won’t let you go back and re-render individual paths of different color if they're already rendered inside the image.

So, the solution is to keep your array of `CGPoint` for the various strokes/paths (called “scribbles” in your app). These might be ones associated with the saved `DamageItem` instances, but we’d want one for the current gesture/touches. Then, when you select a row associated with a particular `DamageItem`, you would discard the saved image and go back and re-render from the array of strokes from scratch, coloring the selected one as appropriate:

```
class Canvas: UIView {
    /// Closure to run on changes to drawing state
    var isDrawingHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?

    /// The cached image drawn onto the canvas
    var image: UIImage?

    /// Caches the path for a line between touch down and touch up.
    public var damages: [DamageItem] = [] { didSet { invalidateCachedImage() } }

    /// The current scribble
    public var currentScribble: [CGPoint]?

    private var predictivePoints: [CGPoint]?

    /// Which path is currently selected
    public var selectedDamageIndex: Int? { didSet { invalidateCachedImage() } }

    /// The colour to use for drawing
    public var strokeColor: UIColor = .black
    public var selectedStrokeColor: UIColor = .orange

    /// Width of drawn lines
    private var lineWidth: CGFloat = 2 { didSet { invalidateCachedImage() } }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        strokePaths()
    }
}

// private utility methods

private extension Canvas {
    func strokePaths() {
        if image == nil {
            cacheImage()
        }

        image?.draw(in: bounds)

        if let currentScribble = currentScribble {
            strokeScribble(currentScribble + (predictivePoints ?? []), isSelected: true)
        }
    }

    func strokeScribble(_ points: [CGPoint], isSelected: Bool = false) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(simpleSmooth: points)
        let color = isSelected ? selectedStrokeColor : strokeColor
        path?.lineCapStyle = .round
        path?.lineJoinStyle = .round
        path?.lineWidth = lineWidth
        color.setStroke()
        path?.stroke()
    }

    func invalidateCachedImage() {
        image = nil
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    /// caches just the damages, but not the current scribble
    func cacheImage() {
        guard damages.count > 0 else { return }

        image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds).image { _ in
            for (index, damage) in damages.enumerated() {
                strokeScribble(damage.scribble, isSelected: selectedDamageIndex == index)
            }
        }
    }

    func append(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?, includePredictive: Bool = false) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

        // probably should capture coalesced touches, too
        if let touches = event?.coalescedTouches(for: touch) {
            currentScribble?.append(contentsOf: touches.map { $0.location(in: self) })
        }

        currentScribble?.append(touch.location(in: self))

        if includePredictive {
            predictivePoints = event?
                .predictedTouches(for: touch)?
                .map { $0.location(in: self) }
        } else {
            predictivePoints = nil
        }

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

// UIResponder methods
extension Canvas {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
        currentScribble = [point]
        selectedDamageIndex = nil

        isDrawingHandler?(true)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        append(touches, with: event)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        append(touches, with: event, includePredictive: false)

        isDrawingHandler?(false)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/tygruletz/AddScribblesOnImage/pull/1 for an example of this implementation. See https://github.com/tygruletz/AddScribblesOnImage/pull/2 for an example where you might have multiple paths as the a set of “scribbles” associated with a particular `DamageItem`.

Note, I’d personally make the “smoothing” of the stroked paths part of the `UIBezierPath` generation process but keep the user’s actual `CGPoint` array in that the model object. I’d also suggest incorporating coalesced touches (to accurately capture the gesture in high frame-rate devices) and predictive touches (to avoid perceived lagginess in the UI). All of this is incorporated in the above pull request.

---

Unrelated, but I might make a few more suggestions:

- I’d rename `Canvas` to be `CanvasView`, as subclasses of `UIView` always bear the suffix `View` as a matter of convention;
- I might suggest contemplating getting out of the process of drawing the paths yourself. I’d generally render paths in `CAShapeLayer` sublayers. That way, you enjoy Apple’s optimizations.

Comment: “as subclasses of UIView always bear the suffix View” Yeah, like UIButtonView, UISwitchView, UIDatePickerView, and UITextFieldView. And all the other UIControlViews.

Comment: Thank you so much Rob for your help !
Can you please help me to understand why I can't see the scribbles on this CanvasView ?
https://github.com/tygruletz/SelectScribbles

Comment: Again, thank you so much Rob !!! Please refer this answer to my question from this post to be able to vote it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58541532/

Comment: I have done so. Feel free to upvote those other two answers as they both capture part of the problem (one tackled the coding alternative, the other tackled some details of the problem with the decoding process). I think that my PR addresses both of those issues, as well as a few others, but they should get credit for their work, too, as they invested the time in your question and identified some of the issues on their own.