# How to display CGPoints on custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a small project which represent an app with reports where the user is able to draw on a custom `CanvasView` and after to select each scribble drawn. When the user click the Save `UIButton` the report will be serialised and saved in `CoreData`. 
After when the user will click on any report to review it will be taken to `DetailsVC` where the report will be deserialised from `CoreData` and will be able to see the scribbles on `CanvasView` but not to draw anymore.
The problem is that is not showing me the scribbles on `CanvasView` (DetailsVC) but in console is saying that the array of scribbles is not empty and was loaded from `CoreData`.

EDIT: I think the problem is on the line below where I think is going through an empty array and is trying to append `CGPoints` but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me to implement a function like:

```
func parseScribbleData(_ bytes: [UInt8]) -> [[CGPoint]] {

}
```

https://github.com/tygruletz/SelectScribbles/blob/master/SelectScribbles/Communications/TTableDeserializer.swift#L34

Here is my demo project: https://github.com/tygruletz/SelectScribbles

Here is a record to reflect the bug (missing CGPoints from `CanvasView`):
[image]

Here is how I deserialize the Scribbles:

```
class TTableDeserializer: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = TTableDeserializer()

    // Deserialize all the damageItems recorded from the Report
    func deserializeDamageItemsFor(report: DefectReport) -> [DamageItem] {

        let damageLinesTTable: TTable = TTable(binaryTable: Data(), format: .bin1)
        var damageItems: [DamageItem] = []

        // Get the DamageList with damage items for selected Report.
        damageLinesTTable.deStreamBin(binaryData: report.damageLines ?? Data(), format: .bin1)

        damageLinesTTable.tableRows.forEach { row in

            var damageItem: DamageItem = DamageItem(name: row.cell[0].sData,
                                                    scribbles: [])

            // All Scribbles
            var allCGPoints = [[CGPoint]]()

            damageItem.scribbles.forEach { scribble in

                var scribbleCGPoints = [CGPoint]()
                scribble.forEach { coordinate in

                    let point = CGPoint(
                        x: CGFloat(UInt8(row.cell[3].iData())),
                        y: CGFloat(UInt8(row.cell[3].iData()) & (~0 >> 1))
                    )
                    scribbleCGPoints.append(point)
                }
                allCGPoints.append(scribbleCGPoints)
            }

            damageItem.scribbles = allCGPoints

            damageItems.append(damageItem)

            print("----------   DESERIALIZATION FOR DAMAGE ITEM '\(row.cell[0].sData.capitalized)' STARTED..........  ----------")
            print("Dmg Item Name:     \(row.cell[0].sData)")
            print("Dmg Item Scribble: \(row.cell[1].binData())")
            print("----------   DESERIALIZATION FOR DAMAGE ITEM '\(row.cell[0].sData.capitalized)' ENDED  ----------\n\n")
        }
        return damageItems
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this pull request](https://github.com/tygruletz/SelectScribbles/pull/1) which address a few issues:

- We want to encode the array of damages in CoreData in such a way that it captures the array of scribbles. Right now you appear to want to store an array of integers, and you really want to capture that `[[CGPoint]]` structure within the `DamageItem`.
- The easiest way to do that is to make `DamageItem` conform to `Codable` and then replace all of that complicated encoding with a standard Foundation coder (I used `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder`).

  That not only captures the richness of the `DamageItem` properly, but radically simplifies encoding/decoding process;

  The encoding is just:

  ```
  report.damageLines = try JSONEncoder().encode(damages)
  ```

  The decoding is then just:

  ```
  let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([DamageItem].self, from: report.damageLines)
  ```
- If you want your `DetailsReport` view controller to enjoy the “select damage and highlight the appropriate scribbles” feature ([like we did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58435138/1271826) for your `CreateReport`), you’ll want to update the custom table cell to capture the selected damage and to have it pass that along to the `CanvasView`.

  You’ll also want `didSelectRowAt` in `DetailsReport` to reload the first section (so you can see the selected damage).

---

Unrelated, I’d also suggest:

- Move `UIBezierPath` routine out of the model folder (as it is not a model).
- Also move `CanvasView` into `View` folder for same reason.

Comment: Thank you Rob for your answer ! Unfortunately when I tried to implement this logic in the main project I figured out that the backend server is not using JSON at all (being old) and is using only this `TTable` (functionality used also by Microsoft) to serialise and deserialise the data and to pass it as Binary Data format.
So I need to find a way to serialise and deserialise that [[CGPoints]] using this TTable class. My progress for Encode + Decode is here but I can't manage to make it work because CGPoints are duplicated:
https://github.com/tygruletz/SelectScribblesUsingBinaryData
Thanks !

Comment: Thank you so so much ! You saved my life ! I debugged 2 days and didn’t found the issue.

Comment: For some reason is showing me only half of the scribbles: http://g.recordit.co/UVOkLV4HOI.gif

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201431/discussion-between-rob-and-flo).

Comment: Sorry @Rob for bothering you but do you have any idea how can I scale and rescale back the CGPoints ? I can't manage to display the scribbles correctly on the screen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No problem @Rob. At the moment I just need to stop the user to draw outside of the canvas because that event is crashing my app. In rest I managed to scale and rescale all the CGPoints.

Comment: Don't worry I fixed the bugs. If you can take a look to see if the code can improved than I will really appreciate ! https://github.com/tygruletz/SelectScribblesUsingBinaryData

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Swift.Codable` to serialize to and deserialize from `Data`.  There is no need to write your own `Data` to `CGFloat` code since `CGFloat` already conforms to `Codable`.  Also `Array<SomeCodable>` is also `Codable` so `[CGFloat]` is also `Codable`.

Convert CGFloat to Data:

```
let numbers: [CGFloat] = [1,2,3,4]
guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(numbers) else {
  fatalError("cannot convert data")
}
```

Convert Data to CGFloat:

```
guard let numbersFromData = try? JSONDecoder().decode([CGFloat].self, from: data) else {
  fatalError("cannot decode floats")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're correct with your assessment of where the issue presents (although I think the problem is a few lines earlier

Your code from Github:

```
 // Get the DamageList with damage items for selected Report.
    damageLinesTTable.deStreamBin(binaryData: report.damageLines ?? Data(), format: .bin1)

    damageLinesTTable.tableRows.forEach { row in

        var damageItem: DamageItem = DamageItem(name: row.cell[0].sData,
                                                scribbles: [])

        // All Scribbles
        var allCGPoints = [[CGPoint]]()

        damageItem.scribbles.forEach { scribble in

            var scribbleCGPoints = [CGPoint]()
            scribble.forEach { coordinate in

                let point = CGPoint(
                    x: CGFloat(UInt8(row.cell[3].iData())),
                    y: CGFloat(UInt8(row.cell[3].iData()) & (~0 >> 1))
                )
                scribbleCGPoints.append(point)
            }
            allCGPoints.append(scribbleCGPoints)
        }
```

in the `damageLinesTTable.tableRows.forEach` block for each row you create a new instance of DamageItem

```
var damageItem: DamageItem = DamageItem(name: row.cell[0].sData,
                                                scribbles: [])
```

Here you are initialising the damageItem variable with an empty array of scribbles.

Then a few liners later you do this:

```
damageItem.scribbles.forEach { scribble in ...
```

to iterate through that array of scribbles.  However that array is always going to be empty as you have just initialised that damageItem with an empty array!

Comment: Yes Flanker you are right. I just edit the post to be more specific for my bug.
I think I need a function to convert that array of bytes [UInt8] to [[CGPoint]].

Comment: First of all you need to find that array of UInt, as at the present it's not obvious where it is coming from.  Has it been deserialised from the binaryDatas and is now a component of the damageLinesTTable?  If so, how is it accessed?